# Flutter: local_auth package returns false upon "Cancel" option

Tags: flutter

I am using local_auth 0.5.2+4 in my project. authenticateWithBiometrics returns false even if the user cancelled biometric authentication or provided wrong fingerprint. Is there a way to know if the user has cancelled biometric authentication?

Comment: This could be related to the issue you are experiencing, I see it is with regards to the authenticateWithBiometrics not displaying anything but returning false, so I thought it could be related. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53826. Perhaps upgrading the version of your package could also help if possible?